# Does the store type Web Feature Server (NG) handle up to a specific number of features?

Tags: geoserver, wfs

I am experiencing problems using the Store type: Web Feature Server (NG) in order to get Features from a remote GeoServer (2.5).

Although when initializing the store there is the possibility to choose:

```
  Maximum number of Features to retrieve (0 = no limit)
```

I made some tests by creating a layer with hundreds of thousand of features and it crashes. It seems like it works only with a few thousands of features but can not handle more.

GeoServer logs return this:

```
Could not acquire feature:java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
java.util.NoSuchElementException: Could not acquire   feature:java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: Rendering process failed

Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Could not acquire feature:java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

In order to create the WFS Cascaded Server I followed the instructions here:

```
http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/adding_data/add_wfscascade.html
```

Leaving the following parameters with default values:

```
Connection and read timeout (ms): 3000
Feature buffer size: 10
Maximum number of Features to retrieve (0 = no limit): 0
```

Comment: please try to reword your post as a question

Comment: You may consider using cascading WFS in a friendly and reasonable way by fetching data with smallish BBOX, some selective filter, or with maxFeatures=10000, for example. The idea of having WFS instead of zipped file for download is to allow to select what you really need.

Comment: try saying what goes wrong - what is in the log? what size of feature are coming back? what is the target? how have you configured geoserver

Comment: @iant tried to become more clear. Greatful if you open it again.

Comment: Test the remote server with browser or curl. If you have timeout at 3 seconds and if the remote server is slower -> you will get a timeout. You can a) make remote service faster if it is yours b) use longer timeout c) restrict the maxFeatures that your client Geoserver is using, or zoom to smaller BBOX and that way help remote server to answer faster.

Comment: @user30184 thanks for the recommendations. Can you please provide some more info regarding your a) make remote service faster if it is yours? I have access in the remote service but how can I make it faster? Are we talking about giving more resources to the server or some fine configuration in the remote geoserver?

Comment: Too broad a question, but when you send WFS request to GeoServer it converts it to request to datastore. If datastore is some database it means making a SQL query. For making it fast the database must have indexes etc. to support that query. And there must be bandwidth to talk with the database, CPU to handle the request, and GeoServer adds some overhead. You must analyze your system, find the bottlenecks and make improvements.

Comment: Great advice @user30184. I see. And I do have one extra layer of interaction as my remote geoserver and the database are in separate servers.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your connection to the remote server is timing out. Without more details of where that server is? and what sort of server it is? and what sort of connection is available it is hard to say where exactly the problem is.

The first thing to try would be a more recent version of GeoServer such as 2.10 as there have been some upgrades to the WFS client code since 2.5.

Comment: The server where the remote geoserver is installed is a container with 4gb ram and 4CPU. The Geoserver in the remote container is 2.10 while the one I create the WFS Cascade is 2.5.  But I am not sure what other info I can provide. What do you mean by connection or type of server?

Comment: but it is your client that is crashing - so upgrade it

Comment: Isn't it just a normal timeout, no crash at all?

Comment: true and he has a 3 second timeout

Comment: Tested with 60seconds and it loads. Extremely slow though. Thanks for the recommendations.

Comment: WFS cascading _is_ slow, with all the GML encoding, transfer and decoding it can hardly be fast. A binary format suitable for streaming should be used to perform faster transfer, but there is no standard one at the moment. There were talks of "binary GML", but haven't seen it implemented in the wild.